# PHP: convert string to DateTime with T

Tags: php, datetime

I have the date(type string): "2018-06-08T14:41:51.000+02:00". I use this code:

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-dTH:i:ue', "2018-06-08T14:41:51.000+02:00"); 
var_dump($date);
```

It returns false. Can you help me ??

Comment: Your formats are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
<?php
$format = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '2018-06-08T14:41:51.000+02:00');
echo 'Date with short format: '.$date->format('Y-m-d H:i');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not test but maybe will work.

```
$time = strtotime('2018-06-08T14:41:51.000+02:00');

$new_time= date('Y-m-d TH:i:ue',$time);

echo $new_time;
```

Comment: This will output only date.

Comment: Y-m-dTH:i:ue: this format is wrong. I want to use the \Datetime function